# SVN file (Piñata.png) with non-ANSI character shows as unversioned and missing

Tags: macos, svn

I have a file named Piñata.jpg.
On Win 8.1, using Tortoise SVN 1.7.12 I can commit and update this file without problems.

However, on OSX 10.8.5 using the svn command line client version 1.8.4, if I do an svn status the file shows as both **!** (missing) and **?** (unversioned).
Obviously it is not both of these at the same time.

If I delete the file and **svn up** it re-downloads the file and shows the same missing and unversioned.

I also tried removing/adding the file to the repo, via Windows, but the result on OSX is the same.

How do I get the file to be correctly recognized?

I tried what is recommended [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176243/problem-with-svn-filename-encoding-on-mac-os-x) but it made no difference.

Comment: Alot more discussion of this issue available at: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2464

Comment: There really isn't a good solution for this yet.  There is a patch floating around that doesn't really solve the problem in sane way (that's attached to the bug you linked above).  This is something we're hoping to solve in 1.9 but the Unicode composition issue is not simple to solve in a compatible way.  The best advice is to simply avoid such path names if interaction with OS X is important to you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I would agree that avoiding such characters is preferable. Unfortunately I inherited this project from another company and it involves iOS development so OSX is a requirement.  I suppose I shall just ignore the problem since I can.