# svn status - Getting ! and ? for same file

Tags: svn

I just checked out a fresh working copy from svn and "svn status" shows ! and ? for the same set of files. So the same file seems to be missing and also unversioned.

```
&> svn status
?       CL002 - Slysatjón F Plús bótaskylt.docx
!       CL002 - Slysatjón F Plús bótaskylt.docx
?       CL025 - Nær ekkisjálfsáb reikn utan.docx
!       CL025 - Nær ekkisjálfsáb reikn utan.docx
```

Are the special characters and spaces causing problems? Again, I have done no changes. This is a fresh checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I find the answer [a here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360811/svn-file-pi%C3%B1ata-png-with-non-ansi-character-shows-as-unversioned-and-missing) just minutes after posting. I am also using OS X and my client version is 1.8.0. There's nothing OS X specific in this repository so I guess I can just ignore this.